# Has anything changed in the past ~48 hours that would break a legacy canvas app using require_login()?

Tags: facebook, redirect, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-iframe, facebook-authentication

Nothing has changed on my end (at least I don't think anything has), but all of a sudden I'm unable to launch my app (and users reportedly are unable to install/launch) which uses the legacy require_login() function from an old version of the PHP SDK.

When I go to apps.facebook.com/myapp, I'm brought into a redirect loop between that URL and http://mysite.com/myAppsCanvasURL.

I've Googled and found some old posts where people report similar behavior but it doesn't seem like there was any resolution, and I still have no idea what could have caused this to happen out of the blue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

- dshap

Comment: What have you tried? What are the error messages? What are the links you've already read? Have you rebuilt or made *any* changes to your code in the last 48 hours? Have you reported the issue to Facebook - and if so, have they responded with any info yet?

Comment: There are no error messages, I definitely would have included them if there were.  Sorry for the frantic post, but right away I just wanted to see if anyone else was experiencing the same issue.  After some looking over the developer roadmap and some suspicion regarding http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/544 , I decided to take out the "user_photo_video_tags" permission request from my require_login() call and sure enough that fixed the problem.  Please correct me if I'm wrong, but this isn't supposed to be deprecated until November, so the fact that it's breaking my app is a bug, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the answer to my own question.

My app requires access to both the user's uploaded photos as well as the user's photo tags.

To do this, I was requesting the (previously) necessary permissions by calling:

```
require_login('user_photos, user_photo_video_tags');
```

According to [this developer blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/544), the "user_photo_video_tags" permission is not supposed to be deprecated until November 22nd, however if I use it right now it breaks my app - if I simply remove it, there are no issues and the app works as expected.

The weird thing is I'm not seeing any exceptions thrown, but then again I'm not seeing any exceptions thrown even if I do something like:

```
require_login('user_photos, fake_permission');
```

So maybe this has something to do with the out-dated version of the PHP SDK that I'm using.

Hopefully that helps if someone else out there is having the same problem.